# Install DC power cable connector on vacuum feedthrough rod

Tags: connector

I would like to know how to install an electrical plug or connector on an electrical vacuum feedthrough. An image of the feedthrough can be seen here: https://us.trinos.com/vacuum_s/trinos-electrical-feedthrough-weld-adapter-from-ht.html

You can click on the small image to see are larger picture of the feedthrough. I know how to make electrical connections on the vacuum side, I just need to connect a DC power cable on the atmospheric side. I would be grateful for any advice on the subject.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the model, the conductor rod thickness corresponds to common thread diameters (e.g. 1/4, 3/8, 3/4). You could thread the ends with a die which can be bought at an autoparts store or hardware store. They also can be easily had from an industrial supplier like Grainger, MSC or McMaster Carr. If you thread the rod, a simple set screw lug can be bought from a hardware store which is used for connecting thick electric wires to terminals. Just use two nuts, washers and a lock washer to secure it to the threaded rod.

For the smaller diameter conductor rods, solder a lead and put a plug on the end. Don't solder the thicker rods.

Answer (score 0):

I would make a screw clamp consisting of a small block with a hole, which can accommodate the copper rod and a wire, and a screw, which is radial to the hole.  Wire and the copper rod go into the hole, the screw clamps them together.  Such terminal doesn't require heating.  It can be taken apart.

Soldering wire to the copper rod should work too.  I don't see what would rule out soldering.

You know how to connect to the feedthrough on the vacuum side.  How are you going to connect on the vaccum side?  What prevents you from using the same method on the atmospheric side?

Comment: I could use a barrel connector with screws on both the vacuum and atmospheric sides, as I think you describe above, but I was hoping to use a coaxial style connector. In any case, thank you for the reply.

Comment: @MarkWahlberg  You can use a coaxial style connector, but you'll probably have to run wires from the feedethrough to the coaxial connector.  The feedthroughs are individual and bulky (obviously).

Answer (score 0):

If you want an easily-removable connection, you could use female contacts from some handy connector family, if you can find some the right size.  Add some heat-shrink tubing to insulate the connection.

Answer (score 0):

See page 14 in this [catalog](http://www.avactec.es/resources/Allectra/ALLECTRA-4-FT.pdf), which covers just about every possible connection method.

[image]